# how to change column values in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select in mysql table that results this:

```
topic user weight  
"hello" 324  3  
"hello" 21   1  
"second thread" 34 1  
"second thread" 21 1  
"second thread" 32 1  
"second thread" 3  3  
"hello" 23   1
```

I would like to turn the first column "topic" into numbers, to simplify things. Is it possible to turn just one column into numbers like this:

```
topic user weight  
1     324  3  
1     21   1  
2     34   1  
2     21   1  
2     32   1  
2      3   3  
1     23   1
```

Many thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Simone

Comment: Is it a fixed set of possible values? If not, it will require making a ranked list to join against (doable, but more complicated)

Comment: Yes you can, read up a bit on `Lookup Tables` and using `JOIN` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method which gets a `DISTINCT` list of topics and assigns row numbers to join against.  This makes it possible to do in one query, plus a variable:

**Edited**: Refactored to initialize the `rownum` variable in the `FROM` clause, which is a little tidier looking and won't produce `n*2` values for the row numbers.

```
SELECT id, yourtable.*
FROM 
  yourtable
  JOIN (
    /* Suquery gets row rank per distinct topic */
    SELECT topic, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS id
    FROM (
      /* Variable initialized in FROM clause */
      SELECT @rownum:=0
    ) sr JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT topic FROM yourtable
    ) t
  ) topicids ON yourtable.topic = topicids.topic
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d53/14

```
ID  TOPIC    USER   WEIGHT
1   "hello"  324    3
1   "hello"  21     1
2   "second" 34     1
2   "second" 21     1
2   "second" 32     1
2   "second" 3      3
1   "hello"  23     1
```

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini Executed how and where? That's an error such as you might get in PHP client code.  Also note that I have updated it above not to require an initial call to set the variable.

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini If you run the query as above directly in a MySQL client, it _will_ work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a temp table?

```
CREATE TABLE temp2 (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  topic varchar(20));

INSERT INTO temp2 (topic)
SELECT DISTINCT topic FROM temp;

SELECT b.id, a.user, a.weight
FROM temp a
INNER JOIN temp2 b ON b.topic = a.topic
```

**Result**

```
| ID | USER | WEIGHT |
----------------------
|  1 |  324 |      3 |
|  1 |   21 |      1 |
|  2 |   34 |      1 |
|  2 |   21 |      1 |
|  2 |   32 |      1 |
|  2 |    3 |      3 |
|  1 |   23 |      1 |
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da6a/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
SELECT
   topic, 
   (SELECT COUNT(topic) FROM yourtable where topic = outer_table.topic),
   user, 
   weight  
FROM 
   yourtable  outer_table
```